# MVC Custom Routing - Users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a custom routing defined like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SpecificCulture",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    culture = ""
                }
            );
```

Now I want to have a special page to display user profiles. So I created a Controller named `Users` with an `Index` action that has `UserName` as argument.

My idea is to be able to acess the users profile throught : http://www.mydomain.com/en-us/Users/JimmyHendrix

I'm not sure how to create this custom routing scenario.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "users",
            url: "{culture}/users/{username}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Users",
                action = "Index",
                culture = "en-US"
            }
        );
```